# Active Setup - script to edit file not running/working

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Have the following batch file:

```
cscript Myvb.vbs "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\file.ini" "Things" "Stuff"
```

vb script file:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = WScript.Arguments(0) 
strFindText = WScript.Arguments(1) 
strNewText = WScript.Arguments(1) & vbCrLf & WScript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, strFindText, stfFindText&strNewText)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write strNewText
objFile.Close

Set objFile = Nothing
```

and batch file to set ActiveSetup:

```
@echo off
REM copy batch file
xcopy Mybat.bat* %SYSTEMROOT%\
xcopy Myvb.vbs* %SYSTEMROOT%\

REM create active setup component to run batch file
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\MySetup" /v "Version" /t REG_SZ /d "1" /f 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\MySetup" /v "StubPath" /t REG_SZ /d "%SYSTEMROOT%\Mybat.bat" /f
```

If mybat is executed manually, the file is edited fine. However, the file does not change after logging in. I undid the changes to the file and cleared the active setup registry entry in my profile between my tests.

Is there a permissions issue I am missing? Is %username% coming out to be not what I expect it to?

Comment: I think you're going to have to troubleshoot this the old-fashioned way:  Try to isolate which step is failing.  Start by having the batch file log its invocation to a log file; for example:  `echo>>C:\MyLog\log.txt %DATE% %TIME% MyBat BEGIN` and `echo>>C:\MyLog\log.txt %DATE% %TIME% MyBat END`.  Don't forget to make the directory in advance, and set permissions for global read/write access.  You might also have to seed it with a log file and set permissions there also.  If both START and END lines show up in the log file, move on to the `.vbs` file and add logging statements there.

Answer (score 1):

Got this working by indicating the full path to the vbs in the bat file

```
cscript "%~dp0Myvb.vbs" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\file.ini" "Things" "Stuff"
```